# How to sequentially call an async function in various time intervals and with different arguments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout, intervals

My goal is to incrementally increase the progress bar when some time have passed after creating an order. To do this, I'd like to call the `updateStatus` async function below at different intervals and with different arguments until the `progress` state reaches 100. Below I've pasted the code for the progress bar.

Chaining `setTimeOut` and `Promise` resulted in the progress bar increasing and decreasing randomly and causing the app to slow down / freeze. What is the proper way to handle what I'm trying to achieve?

```
const ProgressBar = ({ order }) => {
  const { status, order_date } = order;
  const msTillXSeconds = (seconds) => new Date(moment(order_date).add(seconds, 'seconds')).getTime() - Date.now();

  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(progression[status]);
  const [internalStatus, setInternalStatus] = useState(status);

  const updateStatus = async (newStatus) => {
    try {
      const body = { status: newStatus };
      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/orders/${order.order_id}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', token: localStorage.token },
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
      });
      if (response.ok) {
        setProgress(progression[newStatus]);
        setInternalStatus(newStatus);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setProgress(progression[status]);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="progress">
        <div
          className="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated"
          role="progressbar"
          style={{ width: `${progress}%` }}
        >
          {' '}
        </div>
      </div>
      <p className="text-center my-1">{internalStatus}</p>
    </>
  );
};

const STAGES = {
  PENDING: 'Pending Order Confirmation',
  CONFIRMED: 'Order Confirmed',
  PICKING_UP: 'Picking Up',
  EXAMINING: 'Examining',
  SANITIZING: 'Sanitizing',
  RECYCLING: 'Recycling',
};

const progression = {
  [STAGES.PENDING]: 5,
  [STAGES.CONFIRMED]: 20,
  [STAGES.PICKING_UP]: 40,
  [STAGES.EXAMINING]: 60,
  [STAGES.SANITIZING]: 70,
  [STAGES.RECYCLING]: 100,
};
```

Comment: I see no interval or timeout logic. Please show us what you've tried. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass different arguments to your function as a third argument of setTimeout.

```
setTimeout(updateStatus, 1000, ...args)
```

(using your `internalStatus` as `status` in my example)

Also, since status is in your state, you can handle a next setTimeout on a useEffect() hook depending on your logic.

```
useEffect(() => {

   if status something
   otherStatus = somethingElse
   updateOtherStatusAfter = ...

   setTimeout(updateStatus, updateOtherStatusAfter, otherStatus)

}, [ status ] )
```

Observe that status is in the dependency list of useEffect.

This means that every time the status changes, the function that you pass inside the useEffect will be triggered.

After a comment of Drew Reese about clean up, consider something like this.

```
useEffect(() => {

  const tId = setTimeout(...)

  return () => {
     clearTimeout(tId)
  }

}, [ ... ] )
```

Comment: Don't forget to clear any running timers via the `useEffect` cleanup function when the component unmounts.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your problem, you want to call periodically updateStatus AND ensure that the order of updateStatus call is respected.

For this I see two solutions :

- call updateStatus recursively (ie at the end of the function add a setTimeout(...))
- use a promise queue (like https://www.npmjs.com/package/queue-promise) and push to it using a setInterval

In any case, you will need to clean these when component unmounts